# Linux PHP WSHttpBinding integration

Tags: php, linux, wshttpbinding

We run some ecommerce sites and one of our partners would like for us to integrate their stock control. We have done this before from a SOAP web service using basicHttpBinding. We have used this to easily update stock. The problem is when another partner uses WSHttpBinding which seems to be a windows proprietary service which is only supported by .NET and other windows friendly software.

We have found a packing (which is no longer supported adn not updated within 4 years) called "WSO2 Web Services Framework for PHP" https://github.com/wso2/wsf

We cannot get it to install (configure not found), but the fact that there is not much activity for a WSHttpBinding php module leads us to wonder if using a WSHttpBinding service is outdated and obsolete.

Is there a way for Linux PHP to communicate with WSHttpBinding?